# Trying to make a PostgreSQL field with a list of foreign keys in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm, django-migrations

Here is what I'm trying to do:
Make a model in Django that is a PostgreSQL array (database specific type), which contains foreign keys to another model.

```py
class Books(models.Model):
    authors = ArrayField(
        models.ForeignKey('my_app.Authors', default=None, null=True, blank=True),
        blank=True,
        default=list()
    )
```

When I try to makemigrations, Django gives me this error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
my_app.Books.authors: (postgres.E002) Base field for array cannot be a related field.
```

Any Ideas on how to beat that?

Comment: You should use a `ManyToMany` field for this purpose.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can't create an array of foreign keys. It is not a Django limitation, it is a PostgreSQL "limitation".

The reason is that a foreign key is not a type, [it is a constraint on a field](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK). An array of foreign keys does not make any sense.

The general approach to achieve this is to use an intermediate table that will be used as a link between two others :

```
Authors(id, name)
Books(id, title, pub_date)
BookAuthors(id, book_id, author_id)
```

In the above exemple, `BookAuthors.book_id` is a foreign key to `Books.id` and `BookAuthors.author_id` is a foreign key to `Authors.id`. Thus, the table `BookAuthors` is used to match an author with a book and vice versa.

Django abstracts this intermediate table with [`ManyToManyField` fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField):

```py
class Authors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    pub_date = models.DateField(...)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField('my_app.Authors',
                                     related_name='authored_books')
```

Behind the scenes, Django will create the intermediate table.

Then, you can get all authors of a book using `book.authors.all()`, or all books authored by an author using `author.authored_books.all()`.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!
I'll just use the values not as a foreign key instead. I am somewhat worried about performance and the only lime I need these related keys is when I select this object itself.

Comment: I think you should still a many-to-many relation. I you set an array of integers, you will probably go into a lot of troubles. Especially about data integrity. I can't see the issue with performance.

Comment: "An array of foreign keys does not make any sens." Why? Sounds reasonable to me

Comment: @MarcosPereira Because a foreign key is a constraint (like a unique constraint, a primary key or an index) not a data type. You can see a foreign key as a rule that states "Valid values for column author_id must be any primary key of table User".

Comment: Sounds reasonable, just not implemented.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `ManyToManyField`, `ArrayField` can't be related with another model.