# django : arrayfield with custom model as base field

Tags: python, django

I have custom model

```
class customModel(models.Model):
    contents = models.TextField(null=True)
```

and another customModel with ArrayField

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
class customModel2(models.Model):
    ArrayField(customModel()):
```

but it raised errors 
    AttributeError: 'customModel' object has no attribute 'set_attributes_from_name'

```
ArrayField(customModel) also raised similar errors.
```

What are the proper method to define an arrayfield with custom model as base field ?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you didnt set name attribute. Do like this

```
from django.db import models
class CustomModel2(models.Model):
    # making an array of foreign keys of customModel
    # you can also use models.Integer etc
    myArray = ArrayField(
            models.ForeignKey(customModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
            size=8,
        )
```

Comment: Also, this might be helpful since youre using arrayField https://stackoverflow.com/a/51893414/11979793

Comment: It's not possible to use a ForeignKey as a base field for an ArrayField, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957837/trying-to-make-a-postgresql-field-with-a-list-of-foreign-keys-in-django

Comment: @Idocao The restriction is of Postgres, not Django. It can be implemented in other fields. The Question does not mention the use of Postgres. Alternatively, I provided with the manytomany field solution in the first comment.

Comment: @Hashir, `ArrayField` is found in `django.contrib.postgres.fields`. See the `postgres` in the package name? It's not implemented for any other database in Django.